# Anonymous Structures in C found in Unix Kernel

Tags: c, unix, structure

I have started reading the Lions Commentary on Unix v6. I came across these snippets, which I have never seen used in the C language. The author does provide some sort of an explanation, but could someone explain to me what is happening here?

`params.h` :

```
SW 0177570
...... 
struct { int integ; };
```

and this used in `unix/prf.c`

```
if(SW->integ == 0)
```

Explanation by the author

> `SW` is defined previously as the value
>   0177570. This is the kernel address of a
>   read only processor register which stores the
>   setting of the console switch register.
>   The meaning of the statement is clear: get the
>   contents at location 0177570 and see if they
>   are zero. The problem is to express this in
>   C. The code `if (SW == 0)` would not have conveyed this meaning. Clearly
>   `SW` is a pointer value which should be
>   dereferenced. The compiler might have been
>   changed to accept
>   `if (SW-> == 0)`
>   but as it stands, this is syntactically incorrect. By inventing a dummy structure, with
>   an element `integ` , the programmer has found a satisfactory solution to
>   his problem.

My question mainly is how does this work? When the compiler sees `SW->integ`, how does it associate `SW` with the anonymous structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRC, ancient C compilers kept all field names (such as `integ`) in a single namespace instead of creating a namespace per `struct` type. They also did not distinguish between `struct` pointers and `int` pointers, so that every pointer has an `integ` field corresponding to its first `sizeof(int)` bytes. Since `integ` is the first value in a `struct` and has type `int`, `SW->integ` corresponds to `*((int *)SW)`.

Comment: In modern C we'd use `int * const SW = 0177570;` But before the advent of optimizers, that would have cost Ken and his bunch a costly two bytes :)